# Filtrar por uno o mas campos

Tags: html, angularjs

Estoy haciendo un filtro con AngularJS y de momento tengo este código

```
$scope.buscar = function () {
console.log($scope.guia.standby); }
```

Y así con toda una lista de 32 géneros de música.

```
<div class="form-group">
           <label for="sel1">Selecciona un género:</label>
            <select ng-model="guia.standby" class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option value="all">Todos</option>
              <option value="acustico">Acustico</option>  
              <option value="blues">Blues</option>
              <option value="banda">Banda / Metales</option>
              <option value="niños">Niños</option>
              <option value="circo">Circo / Feria</option>
              <option value="clasica">Clasica</option>
```

Mis divs son así

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div ng-if="guia.standby == 'niños'">
          <div class="card h-100"> 
            <a><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">
                <a>Dulces Sueños</a>
              </h4>
              <h5></h5>
              <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              Preview de la canción
              <button onclick="playAudio2()" type="button">Iniciar</button>
              <button onclick="pauseAudio2()" type="button">Pausa </button>
              <br>
              –––––––––––––––––––––––
              Descargar Canción
              <a href="Z:\MUSICA\MÚSICA ORIGINAL\02 - (N.G) infantil, sueños, lullaby, juguetes.wav" download><i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Así si logra filtrar todas los divs que tengan como características "niños" pero hay algunos que tienen hasta 5 generos por ejemplo

4.- Electrónica, Rítmica, pop  -

5.- Rítmica, Electrónica, Pop, Niños -

8.- Funk, Rock, Jazz, Pop -

9.- Electrónica, rock,

¿Cómo puedo hacer para cuando busquen por electronica me salgan todas las que tienen esa característica o cuando busquen por POP igual aunque no sean de solo ese género?

Comment: Hola, si muestras la función de filtrado que tienes hasta el momento ayudaría bastante. Y Donde puedo leer esa característica implícita que dices que es el genero, segun el ejemplo de codigo que muestras no veo nada parecido.

Comment: @ArmandoMartinez encontraste alguna solución a tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas se llaman "filtros", y para lograr lo que necesitas pudieras utilizar un código como el siguiente. Más información sobre filtros en el siguiente enlace: [AngularJS: API:filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="genero in generos" ng-click="addFiltro(genero)">{{genero}}</button>
    <div ng-repeat="cancion in canciones | filter: filterSongs">
        {{ cancion.nombre }} - {{cancion.genero}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('appDemo', [])
        .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http){

            $scope.generos = ['banda', 'salsa', 'pop'];
            
            $scope.canciones = [{
                nombre: 'Cancion de banda',
                genero: 'banda'
            }, {
                nombre: 'Cancion de salsa',
                genero: 'salsa'
            }, {
                nombre: 'Cancion de pop',
                genero: 'pop'
            }]

            $scope.filtros = [];

            $scope.addFiltro = function(filtro) {
                $scope.filtros.push(filtro);
            };
            
            $scope.filterSongs = function(cancion) {
                var temp = $scope.filtros.find(filtro => filtro == cancion.genero);
                return $scope.filtros.length == 0 ? !! true : !!temp;
            };
        });
</script>
```

P.D.
El código solo muestra cómo agregar los filtros que necesitas, eliminarlos ya es tarea tuya.